# if user change url in browser and request was Invalid stay in current page in yii2

Tags: url, yii2, access-control

I want to prevent from IDOR attack in yii2.

If user change url in browser and request was Invalid stay in current page.
I use  below code .I stay the current page and dot render page with id manipulate after change Id by firebug in link page.

But if I change id in browser I redirected to home page.

for example, the user(by Yii::$app->user->identity->id that is 19) is on this page : url http://localhost:8080/profile/test/19 and see own profile. if user  change url to  http://localhost:8080/profile/test/25 in browser and press enter , see the same page again  http://localhost:8080/profile/test/19 That is, his profile but I go to home page, I think Yii::$app->request->referrer in empty in this case.

```
 public function actionTest($id) {

    if (Yii::$app->user->identity->id == $id) {
        return $this->render('view', [
                    'model' => User::findOne($id),
        ]);
    } else {

        $this->goBack(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using [access control filters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-filters#access-control) for this or/and maybe simple [RBAC system](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#rbac). Referrer can be modified and you can end up in endless loop for example.

Comment: @Bizley RBAC or access controls use for any level control.I have control access for own values,

Comment: The important thing for me is that in case of invalid access and manipulation of the update ID in browser, I can stay on the same page as before.